# Writing unit test with render() return

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a class that looks like

```
class Navigation extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <bunch_of_html>
        )
    }
}

export default Navigation
```

When I try to test it, I call

```
import NavigationBar from './index';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import {configure, shallow, mount, render} from "enzyme";
import Navigation from './Navigation';

describe('<Nav />', () => {
    it('should render', () => {
        const rendered = renderer.create(<Navigation />);
        expect(rendered.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

But I keep getting `<Navigation /> › encountered a declaration exception` and `TypeError: Expected a string`

I don't have enough info to debug from here. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: put a `debugger;` in the beginning of the `it`. And run jest with `node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand` like mentioned here https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting or set up a repo we can download and test for ourselves

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. I did what you said and ran `npm test` again and no debugger logs show up. Am I missing something?

Comment: you should run the command specifically mentioned and not `npm test`, unless your reconfigured it. If you run the command I gave you you can open chrome dev tools and click the green icon near mobile vision icon to the left of Elements panel tab it will open the debugger session from node.

Comment: Sorry I'm very confused. I ran the command and opened the devtool. What do I do next?

Comment: https://discourse-cdn-sjc1.com/meteor/uploads/default/original/2X/2/2b7444c5da43df91db5e6694c098d86b2d238534.png do you see this green icon? Click it. If you don't see the icon then probably you didn't run the command I sent you. You need to specifically call node with --inspect-brk with existing `debugger;` statement in the  source code to make it all work.

Comment: yea I saw the green icon, clicking it opens the devtool. Then I'm lost again. Sorry compete noob here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177381/discussion-between-karen-grigoryan-and-jchao).